# How to user data in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have to database model: `User` and `Conversations`. `User` model this schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   logo: String,
   .....
})
```

and `Conversation` schema:

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   messages: [Object],
   recipients:[String] ,
   .....
})
```

in `recipents` array I save only `user _id's`. I have this questions: If I have many Conversation and I want to get User data by each conversation recipents. Can I get in one mongoose find query all conversation recipient user data? For example: I send:

```
{
 {
  recipients: ['12asdad','dsdadsa',....]
 },
{
  recipients: ['sdasadad','sdadd',....]
 },
{
  recipients: ['sdad','sadadsd',....]
 },
....

}
```

and I want to get this:

```
{
   [Userdata1, Userdate2,....],
   [Userdata., Userdate?,....],
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mongoose `ref` to reference another schema.
Your schema should be like this:

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   messages: [Object],
   recipients:[{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'User'
    }] ,
   .....
})
```

and you can use populate to get the user data. Take a look at this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html